# checkbox error in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

```
        <?php
        $i= 0;
        foreach($purchaseorder as $tdata):
         $i++; 
       ?>
       <tr >


         <td><?php echo $tdata['pay_date']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $tdata['cylinder']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $tdata['amount']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $tdata['rtgs_no']; ?></td> 
         <td><?php echo $tdata['cheque_no']; ?></td> 
         <td><?php echo $tdata['dd_no']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo if ($tdata['approve']=='true')
         {
         ?>
         <img src="/../img/green.png" alt="alt-tag"/>;
         <?php
         }
         else 
         {
         ?>
         <img src="/../img/red.png" alt="alt-tag" />;

        <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php
       endforeach;  
       ?>
```

my code is when i check a checkbox and submit a green tick should be displayed in list page..if its not checked and submitted a red cross should be  displayed..but i get a error in the above code..what sholud i do?

Comment: Can you mention what errors you get?

Comment: user this code `if ($tdata['approve']==true)`. remove quote from true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><?php if ($tdata['approve']=='true')
         { ?>
         <img src="/../img/green.png" alt="alt-tag"/>
         <?php }
         else 
         { ?>
         <img src="/../img/red.png" alt="alt-tag" />
         <?php } ?></td>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
    foreach($purchaseorder as $tdata):
   ?>
   <tr >
     <td><?php echo $tdata['pay_date']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $tdata['cylinder']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $tdata['amount']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $tdata['rtgs_no']; ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $tdata['cheque_no']; ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $tdata['dd_no']; ?></td> 
     <td><?php if($tdata['approve']==true)
     {
     ?>
     <img src="/../img/green.png" alt="alt-tag"/>;
     <?php
     }
     else 
     { ?>
     <img src="/../img/red.png" alt="alt-tag" />;
    <?php
     } ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <?php
   endforeach;  
   ?>
```

try this code and if possible show me the data thats comes on "$purchaseorder" variable

Answer (score 0):

First make var_dump($tdata) and look 'approve' index value. If is set $tdata['approve'] then change code:

```
<td><?php if ($tdata['approve']=='true')
         { ?>
         <img src="/../img/green.png" alt="alt-tag"/>
         <?php }
         else 
         { ?>
         <img src="/../img/red.png" alt="alt-tag" />
         <?php } ?></td>
```

for this

```
<?php
$approveImg = ($tdata['approve']=='true') ? 'green.png' : 'red.png';
?>
<td>
    <img src="/../img/<?=$approveImg?>" alt="alt-tag"/>
</td>
```

Also check paths to images